# Wrap-around in SQL results ordering

Tags: sql

If I have a table with items beginning with C, D, and J, is it in any way possible to arrange a query that orders these ascending, but starts with D, and ends with C wrapped around?

E.g. raw table = C,C,C,D,D,J
Desired result order = D,D,J,C,C,C

In ordinary SQL this is, not any functional language?  I can't see how the desired order can be achieved without hard-coding, i.e. selecting each individual record in the desired order all union'd together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not seem like a regular order, so you won't be able to do it in a simple way. But you can do this:

```
(SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE ID >=C ORDER BY ID) UNION (SELECT SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE ID <C ORDER BY ID)
```

Comment: Very close to what I ended up doing, except for T-SQL I had to use derived tables with a top clause to be allowed an 'ORDER BY' in union parts.  Luckily T-SQL allows dynamic TOP, so I could use "select top (select COUNT(*) from Person) * from Person" blah blah.  Exact answer coming later.

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce a custom sort key with a CASE statement.

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3,
       case left(Col3,1) when 'D' then 1
                         when 'J' then 2
                         when 'C' then 3
                         else 4
       end as SortKey
    from YourTable
    order by SortKey, Col3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom sort orders without hardcoding by using a table:

```
CREATE TABLE SortRules (
    Prefix char(1) NOT NULL
    ,SortOrder int NOT NULL
)
```

Then join to the SortRules table:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
LEFT JOIN SortRules
    ON YourTable.YourColumn LIKE SortRules.Prefix + '%'
ORDER BY SortRules.SortOrder, YourTable.YourColumn
```

You can make SortOrder UNIQUE (although that's not required).  You can also decide if you want missing ones (unmatched in the join) to be at the top or bottom:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
LEFT JOIN SortRules
    ON YourTable.YourColumn LIKE SortRules.Prefix + '%'
ORDER BY COALESCE(SortRules.SortOrder, 2147483647), YourTable.YourColumn

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
LEFT JOIN SortRules
    ON YourTable.YourColumn LIKE SortRules.Prefix + '%'
ORDER BY COALESCE(SortRules.SortOrder, -2147483648), YourTable.YourColumn
```